# Is $\sum_i c_i (x^{n_i} + x^{-n_i} ) \ge 0$ for $\sum_i c_i =0$ and $\sum_i c_i n_i^2 > 0$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials, roots

Let $ f(x) = \sum_i c_i (x^{n_i} + x^{-n_i} )$ for an index set $\{i\}$ with $n_i \in \cal{{N}}_0$; $\sum_i c_i = 0$, and $c_i >0 $ for the maximum $n_i$.

Further, it is required that   $\sum_i c_i n_i^2 >  0$, which ensures that a local minimum is observed at  $x=1$.

Then prove or disprove that $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x > 0$, where equality occurs only  for $x=1$.

Some examples for explanation:

$f_1(x) = x^2 + x^{-2} -2$ satisfies the conditions with $c_1 = 1, n_1 = 2$ and $c_2 =-1, n_2 = 0$. Indeed, $f_1(x) = (x^1 - x^{-1})^2 \ge 0$ with equality only for $x = 1$.

$f_2(x) = x^4 + x^{-4} -3  x^2 -3 x^{-2} + 2 x + 2 x^{-1}$ satisfies the conditions with $c_1 = 1, n_1 = 4$ ; $c_2 = -3, n_2 = 2$ and $c_3 =2, n_3 = 1$. Indeed, $f_2(x) =(x - 1)^2 (x^6 + 2 x^5 + 2 x + 1)/x^4 \ge 0$ with equality only for $x = 1$.

A number of other trials showed no counterexamples.

Descartes rule of signs gives only a partial result since there can be numerous changes in the signs of the $\{c_i\}$.

Comment: Equivalently, we wish to show that $\sum_ic_i\cosh tn_i>0$ for all $t>0$ such that $\sum_ic_i=0$ and $\sum_ic_in_i^2>0$.

Let $n_i\ge n_j$ for all $i>j$ so $c_1>0$. To minimise our expression, we have $n_1\ge n_2+1$ as otherwise $c_2$ must also be positive. By writing $$\sum_ic_i\cosh tn_i=\sum_i\sum_{k\ge1}c_i\frac{t^{2k}n_i^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\frac{t^2}2\sum_ic_in_i^2+\frac{t^4}{24}\sum_ic_in_i^4+\cdots$$ it appears each of these terms is positive (that is, $\sum_ic_in_i^{2k}\ge\sum_ic_in_i^2$) due to the leading $n_1$ term, but I haven't got a rigorous argument yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A counterexample:
$$
\begin{align}
 f(x) &= (x^3+x^{-3}) - 50 \cdot(x^2+x^{-2}) + 200 \cdot(x + x^{-1}) - 151\cdot 2 \\
 &= \frac{(x-1)^2(x^4-48 x^3+103 x^2-48 x+1)}{x^3}
\end{align}
$$
satisfies the given conditions, but $f(2) = -51/8 < 0$.

*Remark:* This was inspired by the representation
$$\sum_ic_i\cosh tn_i=\frac{t^2}2\sum_ic_in_i^2+\frac{t^4}{24}\sum_ic_in_i^4+\cdots
$$
suggested by [@TheSimpliFire](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/471884/thesimplifire) in a comment to the question. While trying to prove or disprove that
$$
 c_N > 0, \sum_{n=1}^N c_n = 0, \sum_{n=1}^N n^2 c_n > 0 \implies \sum_{n=1}^N n^4 c_n > 0
$$
I found the counterexample $(c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3) = (-151, 200, -50, 1)$ which satisfies
$$
 c_0 + c_1 + c_2 + c_3 = 0 \, ,\\
 c_1 + 4 c_2 + 9 c_3 = 9 > 0 \, , \\
 c_1 + 16 c_2 + 81 c_3 = -519 < 0 \, . \\
$$
Luckily, that lead also to a counterexample for the original problem. More counterexamples can found in a similar way.

Comment: Very nice, Martin, thank you!

Comment: Inspired from your approach: suppose you strengthen the problem by additionaly demanding $ \sum_ic_in_i^4 > 0$. Do you think that one then finds a sequence of $\{c_i, n_i\}$ which satisfies that and still fails $f(x) \ge 0$ ? Of course, in that case you could additionally demand   $ \sum_ic_in_i^6 > 0$ etc. - will this propagation end? Or will there always be  a sequence of $\{c_i, n_i\}$ which satisfies all previous demands and still fails $f(x) \ge 0$ ?

Comment: @Andreas: My guess would be that a finite number of constraints of the form $\sum_ic_in_i^{2k} > 0$ is not sufficient to guarantee positiveness of $f$. But getting concrete counterexamples might be more difficult.